# How do I add values of all columns of list view in Android?

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I have created a list view in which I have a product name, price and quantity for each list item. I want to get the sum of total quantity, but I am not able to do so.

How can I do it?

The code I have used using product list: adapter code

private  void setTotalQuantity(TextView textview)
    {

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i< dataSet.size();i++)
    {


        totalquantity =         totalquantity+Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductQuantity());

        totalbill = totalbill+Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductPrice()) * Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductQuantity());
    }

}
```

// add or subtraction button

```
     private void subtractQuantity(final ImageView imageView, final TextView textView) {

    String qty = textView.getText().toString();

    if (Integer.parseInt(qty) == 0)

    {
        imageView.setClickable(false);
    } else {
        imageView.setClickable(true);
        qty = Integer.parseInt(qty) - 1 + "";
        textView.setText(qty);
        data.setProductQuantity(qty);
        setTotalQuantity(txtQtyAll);
    }

}


private void AddQuantity(final ImageView add, final TextView textView, final  ImageView minus) {

    String qty = textView.getText().toString();


    qty = Integer.parseInt(qty) + 1 + "";

    textView.setText(qty);
    data.setProductQuantity(qty);
    setTotalQuantity(txtQtyAll);
    if(Integer.parseInt(qty) >0)
    {
        minus.setClickable(true);
    }


}
```

getting null pointer exception

http://prntscr.com/ecau0x

// updated code

```
       private void subtractQuantity(final ImageView imageView, final TextView textView) {

    String qty = textView.getText().toString();

    if (Integer.parseInt(qty) == 0)

    {
        imageView.setClickable(false);
    } else {
        imageView.setClickable(true);
        qty = Integer.parseInt(qty) - 1 + "";
        textView.setText(qty);
        data.setProductQuantity(qty);
        setTotalQuantity(txtQtyAll);
    }

}
```

and

```
        public AdapterProductListing(List<ProductModel> dataModels, Context context, TextView quantity) {
    this.dataSet = dataModels;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.txtQtyAll = quantity;


}
```

txtQtyAll  is the textview which I got from activity

Comment: Sum of total quantity? So why you use getProductPrice()?

Comment: please provide the relevant code and be clear in asking question . As here you was asking for quantity then what is the need of this code.

Comment: I have just used it to check @ZakiPathan

Comment: first check your products list. Is it contain value correctly? because this above code is correct

Comment: I need to get total items in cart and total amount (bill) based on price and quantity. Actually I am not able to get how to do it. @ZakiPathan

Comment: check my answer. If you getting correct values in your arrayList this works perfectly @MukeshMishra

Comment: setTotalQuantity(txtQtyAll); where is this function? and what is txtQtyAll?

Comment: check updated code @ZakiPathan

Comment: but where is setTotalQuantity function code? @MukeshMishra

Comment: private  void setTotalQuantity()
    {

        for(int i = 0 ; i< dataSet.size();i++)
        {


            totalquantity = totalquantity+Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductQuantity());
            txtQtyAll.setText(totalquantity);

            totalbill = totalbill+Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductPrice()) * Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductQuantity());
        }

    }

Comment: So where you are using textview in this fuction code?  for(int i = 0 ; i< dataSet.size();i++)
    {


        totalquantity =         totalquantity+Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductQuantity());

        totalbill = totalbill+Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductPrice()) * Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductQuantity());
    }

Comment: are you getting correct values in dataSet? please check that first @MukeshMishra

Comment: If possible post your dataSet data in question it helps to solve this @MukeshMishra

Comment: yes, getting correct values

Comment: I think that you are now update "data" which is local variable in getView(). Please try adding setTag(position) to your add and substract buttons. Inside their onClickListener(), use getTag() to get the position and update the datalist. I have a blog about ListView: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/ which have samples on how to implement it. Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int totalQuantity=0;
for(int i = 0 ; i<products.size();i++)
    totalQuantity+=Integer.valueOf(products.get(i).getQuantity());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you showed all the code that's involved. Are you trying to get the total price of all products?

Assuming you initialized "int total" already and the method getProductPrice() is ok, you can do this:

```
total += Integer.parseInt(products.get(i).getProductPrice());
```

Check your error logs as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<products.size();i++)
{
    totalprice = totalprice+Integer.parseInt(products.get(i).getProductPrice());

 totalquantity = totalquantity+Integer.parseInt(products.get(i).getProductQuantity());

 totalbill = totalbill+Integer.parseInt(products.get(i).getProductPrice() * products.get(i).getProductQuantity());
}
```

try this

Comment: I want o ask you one more query  i,e I have an adapter and a list view activity so where I should use this code so that it will update continuously as per the items adding or deletion process is going on. Because I have used the same code but not able to update continuously.

Comment: I tried it but getting null pointer exception I am going to update question check it again

Comment: you dont getting the values in your products arraylist please check that first @MukeshMishra

Comment: I have solved problem but not able to get  total quantity using above code @Zaki

Comment: what you try @MukeshMishra till now?

Comment: for(int i = 0 ; i< dataSet.size();i++)
    {


        totalquantity =         totalquantity+Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductQuantity());

        totalbill = totalbill+Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductPrice()) * Integer.parseInt(dataSet.get(i).getProductQuantity());
    }    used this code but product quantity is 0

Comment: so check your setProductQuantity where you set quantity. In that you got some data or not? @MukeshMishra